# Javascript Check if hour is between two hours from client to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, dayjs

I need to know if an hour is between two hours, for this I have the following algorithm:

```
const startHour = dayjs( startTime ).hour();
const startMinute = dayjs( startTime ).minute();

const endHour = dayjs( endTime ).hour();
const endMinute = dayjs( endTime ).minute();

filteredData = data.filter( ( item ) => {

    const hour = dayjs.unix( item.generatedAt ).hour();
    const minute = dayjs.unix( item.generatedAt ).minute();

    if ( hour >= startHour && hour <= endHour ) {
        if ( hour === startHour && minute < startMinute ) {
            return false;
        }
        if ( hour === endHour && minute > endMinute ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    return false;

} );
```

The thing is that my client is in gmt-4 and the server is in utc, so if my client chooses a time, such as 22:00 p.m., this will make this time 2:00 am on the server, so the condition is going to be false.

How could I correct this error?

I am using the dayjs library.

Answer (score 1):

you should adjust timezone for the time from server like below:

```
const startHour = dayjs( startTime ).tz("UTC").hour();
const startMinute = dayjs( startTime ).tz("UTC").minute();

const endHour = dayjs( endTime ).tz("UTC").hour();
const endMinute = dayjs( endTime ).tz("UTC").minute();
```

Comment: That is, would I have to send the user's time zone from the client to the server in order to adjust the hours on the server?